# Signifying unsaved changes by prepending * in window title - how to add a black dot in the window close button on Mac OS X?

Tags: tkinter, cross-platform, tk-toolkit

I am writing a text editor in Tkinter, using a `TopLevel` window that includes a `Text` widget. Currently, when a document/buffer contains unsaved changes, I prepend the title of the window with an asterisk as in `MyDocument` -> `*MyDocument` , as customary under *nix environments. For that purpose, I am using the `edit_modified` method of `Text` as follows:

```py
import Tkinter as tk
class EditingWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    # [...]

    self.text = tk.Text(...)

    # track modifications of the text:
    self.text.bind("<<Modified>>", self.modified)

    def modified(self, event=None):
        if self.text.edit_modified():
            title=self.title()
            if title[0] != '*':
                self.title("*" + title)
        else:
            title=self.title()
            if title[0] == '*':
                self.title(title[1:])

    def save(self, event=None):
        # [... saving under a filename kept in the variable self.filename ...]
        self.text.edit_modified(False)
        self.title(os.path.basename(self.filename))
```

**My question is:** On Mac OS X, rather than prepending the window title with an asterisk, a black dot appears in the window close button (the red circular button on the topleft corner) to signify unsaved changes. Is it possible to access this feature from Tkinter (or, more generally, from Tcl/Tk)?

**Edit 2:** 
After initial suggestions to use applescript, Kevin Walzer came up with the solution: setting `tkinter`'s `wm_attributes`. Above, that amounts to using

```py
self.wm_attributes("-modified", 1) # sets black dot in toplevel's close button (mac)
```

and

```py
self.wm_attributes("-modified", 0) # unsets black dot in toplevel's close button (mac)
```

in `self.modified`.

Comment: In all my years of using a mac I've never noticed a black dot in the close button. What application does that?

Comment: Well, it seems it depends indeed on the application and the OS X version: TextEdit (mac os x 10.6.8, but not os x 10.7.5?), Emacs, LibreOffice, MSWord (both os x versions)

Comment: Most OS X apps use this black dot to indicate that the current document has changed (Mail is one example). Starting with Lion, it is not used by apps that instead use the OS-level version control.

Comment: No idea if you can call OS functions with tkinter, but you are looking to use IsWindowModified and SetWindowModified, at least on Carbon.

Comment: (Just wondering how the Lion os can know about changes in an application's internal buffer?) Thanks for pointing to these functions. Can they be called through applescript? (And would you know how?) For example, one can force the tkinter window to be raised on os x by calling /usr/bin/osascript -e using Python's os.system call: see e.g. http://fyngyrz.com/?p=898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using wm_attributes and setting the "modified" flag to true.

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root= Tk();
Label(root,text='This is the Toplevel').pack(pady=10)
root.wm_attributes("-modified", 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that feature was added. Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: Fantastic, that works perfectly, thanks so much! Had never come across wm_attributes before, good to know. I've edited the original question to remove any reference to applescript.